# Is there a simple way to delay a call for about 5 seconds without blocking the caller thread?

Tags: c#

I know I can use Thread.Sleep(5000), but it blocks the thread. I would like to delay the call for 5 seconds, but not block the thread.

Comment: You can use Timer, Task.Delay etc

Comment: `await Task.Delay(5000);`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` for this. Set its interval to 5000 ms i.e. 5 seconds and hood its elapsed event to write your code.

For more on timers read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx)

Comment: Which timer `System.Windows.Forms.Timer `, `System.Threading.Timer` or `System.Timers.Timer` ?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to fork it of to the [threadpool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbf0f1ct.aspx):

```
 ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => { Thread.Sleep(5000); DoSomething(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Task.Factory to raise a new thread. Even if you call Thread.Sleep, your main thread isn't blocked. I'm not saying this is the best practise, but you requested a simple way. And this is the simplest I can quickly come up with.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            // wait for 5 seconds or user hit Enter key cancel the task
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            DoStuff();
        });

        Console.WriteLine("Here's the main thread.");
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void DoStuff()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Task done!");
    }
}
```

This will output:

> ```
> Here's the main thread.
> Task done!
> ```

In .NET 4.5 this would become even simpler

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DoStuff(5000);
        Console.WriteLine("Here's the main thread.");
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static async void DoStuff(int delay = 0)
    {
        await Task.Delay(delay);
        Console.WriteLine("Task done!");
    }
}
```

The output would be same:

> ```
> Here's the main thread.
> Task done!
> ```

Keep in mind, you have to mark the method `async` if you wish to use `await`.

Answer (score -3):

**.NET 4.5**

In the context of a UI framework, they have a specialized threading context. You see, to manipulate the UI the code must run on the UI owning thread or you will get unhandled exceptions. Thus, once an asynchronous Task is returned from an event handler, the UI framework will schedule the completion event into an internal queue. At some point, the completion is raised and the UI thread will handle the completion for those mentioned restrictions. For UI contexts, you can use:

```
async void MyButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
  await Task.Delay(5000); // UI thread context for the win
  DoYourCall();
}
```

At any other given situation where that specialized threading context does not exist, performing an await will suspend the calling thread to actually perform the await as the word suggests. The state is still in memory, but the thread detaches and schedules the thread pool to give a thread from the pool when the completion happens (thus, the default behavior). Use the following.

```
Task.Run(async () => {
  await Task.Delay(5000);
  DoYourCall();
});
```

**.NET 4.0**

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
  Thread.Sleep(5000);
  DoYourCall();
});
```

Comment: No need for `Task.Run`.   `await Task.Delay(5000);   DoYourCall();` is enough

Comment: That will block (or actually, reschedule) the calling thread, the OP explicitly mentioned he does not want that.

Comment: No it will not block the calling thread.

Comment: Please read up on `async/await` mechanics if you are confused. The calling thread will have its state suspended and rescheduled to continue once the event on which is awaited is fired. The actual thread is released, and a random available thread from the thread pool is obtained once the event is launched. The calling "thread" will have been suspended during that time, resulting in behavior like blocking. That's simply how this mechanism was designed.

Comment: Roel try this `async void Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("a");
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        Console.WriteLine("b");
    }` If **you** are confused. (Call it in, for ex, Form_Load event)

Comment: BTW: VS is open in front of me, and I tested it.

Comment: Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx at "What happens in an Async method".

Comment: Roel, Testing it would have taken your less time than writing unnecessary comments.

Comment: Updated for y'all that only know how the UI seems to work.

Comment: @I4V your test is in some way incorrect, since I've just performed the same test in both a console application and a windows forms application, and correctly demonstrated a delay of 5 seconds using this method.